# How to get the difference between two rows in a table and place in a new column through SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access, plsql

```
select * from TABLE1
where ENTRY_DATE >=trunc(sysdate-365)
 ORDER BY ENTRY_TIME
```

This gives me the following result:

```
NUMBER_ID | ENTRY_DATE | ENTRY_TIME
----------+------------+------------
        1 | 11/21/2014 | 11/21/2014 08:05:00 AM 
        2 | 11/21/2014 | 11/21/2014 08:08:46 AM 
        3 | 11/21/2014 | 11/21/2014 08:09:51 AM 
        4 | 11/21/2014 | 11/21/2014 08:10:05 AM 
        5 | 11/21/2014 | 11/21/2014 08:10:05 AM 
        6 | 11/21/2014 | 11/21/2014 08:10:59 AM 
        7 | 11/21/2014 | 11/21/2014 08:14:34 AM
```

However I would like to be able to display "Difference" through SQL, where column "Difference" is the difference in time between one entry and the last.

[What I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjtTK.png)

Can anyone help with adding this to my this SQL code? Thanks

Comment: What is the actual DB you are using? You need `lag` function. Google it for your database. It is very easy to implement.

Comment: you should avoid pictures but use text for displaying the data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have specified multiple RDBMS. For oracle, a straightforward query would be

```
    SELECT e_id
         , e_d - NVL(LAG ( e_d ) OVER ( ORDER BY e_d ), e_d) diff
      FROM events
         ;
```

assuming a base table `events` created by

```
    CREATE TABLE events ( e_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, e_d DATE );
```

The difference will be presented in the unit 'days'.

An alternative query does not use the `LAG` function and - while stillbeing formulated in oracle syntax - should be portable:

```
    SELECT e.e_id
         , NVL ( e.e_d - elagged.e_d, 0 ) diff
      FROM events e
 LEFT JOIN events elagged  ON ( elagged.e_id = e.e_id - 1 )
  ORDER BY e.e_id
         ;
```

[This sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/224b4/5) contains the complete example.

Comment: Spot on! Thanks a million :)